# Teniendo Tres Listas Dadas, Generar una Matriz 3x3

Tags: python

Tengo tres listas con información especifica en cada una:

```
puntoDistribucion = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
cajasEntregadas  = [98, 86, 99, 89, 89]
tiempoDespacho = [11, 14, 11, 12, 12]
```

Necesito tomar esa información y generar una matriz 3x3 que quede de esta manera:

```
arreglo = ([1, 98, 11], [2, 86, 14], [3, 99, 11], [4, 89, 12], [5, 89, 12])
```

y que la salida impresa se vea así:

```
1 98 11 
2 86 14 
3 99 11 
4 89 12 
5 89 12
```

He intentado de varias formas y no encuentro la manera de hacerlo. La verdad estoy perdido y dando tumbos lo que mas creí que me serviría es el siguiente código:

```
arreglo = ([])
for i in range(len(puntoDistribucion)):
    for j in range(len(cajasEntregadas)):
        for k in range(len(tiempoDespacho)):
            print(arreglo[i][j][k], end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el código de tus intentos?

Comment: Podrías darle un vistazo a [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: Muchas gracias, excelentes respuestas, me sirvieron bastante para resolver el problema. Continuo aprendiendo mucho con ustedes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías utilizar [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) que devuelve un iterador para recorrer las 3 listas a la vez. Ambas tienen la misma cantidad de elementos por lo que no tendrás problemas:

```
lista_final = []
for punto, caja, tiempo in zip(puntoDistribucion, cajasEntregadas, tiempoDespacho):
    lista_final.append([punto, caja, tiempo])
```

Si imprimes el resultado de `lista_final` veràs lo siguiente:

```
[[1, 98, 11], [2, 86, 14], [3, 99, 11], [4, 89, 12], [5, 89, 12]]
```

Podrías también usar `numpy` con su método `matrix` para crear la matriz (además de lo que ya tienes).

```
# Lo importamos:
import numpy

puntoDistribucion = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
cajasEntregadas  = [98, 86, 99, 89, 89]
tiempoDespacho = [11, 14, 11, 12, 12]

lista_final = []
for punto, caja, tiempo in zip(puntoDistribucion, cajasEntregadas, tiempoDespacho):
    lista_final.append([punto, caja, tiempo])

print(numpy.matrix(lista_final))
```

De esta manera el resultado sería:

```
[[ 1 98 11]
 [ 2 86 14]
 [ 3 99 11]
 [ 4 89 12]
 [ 5 89 12]]
```

Tienes  [algunas guías de instalación](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-numpy) , en internet. Si estás en Ubuntu o Debian por ejemplo, podrías instalarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
# Python 2:
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install numpy
# Python 3:
pip3 install numpy
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: No hace falta que crees una lista vacía y vayas añadiendo los elementos. Puedes usar una compresión: `lista_final = [list(x) for x in zip(a,b,c)]`, con sus respectivos valores. Obtienes el mismo resultado y te ahorras dos lineas de código.

Answer (score 1):

La función `zip` es lo que necesitas.

Esta función es un iterable toma dos o más iterables y te devuelve una n-tupla formada tomando un valor de cada uno de los iterables:

```
puntoDistribucion = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
cajasEntregadas  = [98, 86, 99, 89, 89]
tiempoDespacho = [11, 14, 11, 12, 12]

matriz = []

for x, y, z in zip(puntoDistribucion, cajasEntregadas, tiempoDespacho):
    matriz.append([x, y, z])

for lista in matriz:
    print(*lista)
```

produce:

```
1 98 11
2 86 14
3 99 11
4 89 12
5 89 12
```

Para imprimir usamos `print(*lista)`, con un "*" por delante de lista, lo que expande la lista, siendo equivalente a escribir el desglose `print(lista[0], lista[1], lista[2])`